# append element to cell in matlab

Tags: matlab, list, append

In order to "python-like append" elements to a Matlab list I use the following iteration

```
list = [element1 element2 ... ; list]
```

it works fine if the list elements are either numbers or characters. But it does not work if I try to combine them. I am looking to append 2x1 vectors (char number) to a Matlab list. Any suggestion?

Comment: You want to use a cell array, which allows you to store elements of mixed types in the same data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB doesn't have lists. If you try to convert Python 1-to-1 to MATLAB, you'll run into all sorts of problems. It's worth while taking a little bit of time to learn about how MATLAB handles data if you will be programming in MATLAB. The makers of MATLAB have some really good online tutorials for beginners (it's free!).

In MATLAB everything is an array. There are numeric, logical, character and cell arrays, as well as struct arrays and object arrays. The difference between these is of course what is inside each array. The cell array is the only one that is heterogeneous (i.e. contains elements of different types), because each cell is an array of arbitrary type. (The struct array is also a heterogeneous storage, but each element of the array is a struct with the same fields, so it's still consistent that way.)

So for example, MATLAB doesn't have a double-float type. It's `double` type is an array of double-float values. `v = 1` creates such an array with a single value.

---

So what you are trying to do is:

```
list = {};
list = [ {element1}, {element2}, ..., list ];
```

The curly braces create a cell array. `{element1}` is a cell array containing a single element. The square brackets, as you know, concatenate elements of the same type. Here we are concatenating a bunch of cell arrays.

An alternative to the above syntax is:

```
list = { element1, element2, ..., list{:} };
```

Here, `list{:}` is a comma-separated list of the elements in the cell array `list`. All elements, old and new, are concatenated in a cell array. The curly braces do like the square brackets, but concatenate elements of different type in a cell array.

---

If you want to *append* (that is always at the end) elements to the cell array, one element at the time, the best way is to do this:

```
list = {};
for ...
   list{end+1} = new_element;
end
```

This is much more efficient than the alternatives (at least on MATLAB R2017a -- it is possible they'll optimize their JIT for these alternatives at some point):

```
list = {};
for ...
   list = [list, {new_element}]; % DON'T DO THIS!
end
for ...
   list = {list{:}, new_element}; % DON'T DO THIS!
end
```

The same is true for extending any other array type.