# MATLAB list-like data structure

Tags: matlab

Does MATLAB have a data structure to which elements can be added and removed without copying all of data?

AFAIK it lacks a list (like in Python), so I'm trying to implement it, but unsure what to build it on. I figured cell array, but the linter suggests it's actually an array. One could implement it the long way where each element is a separate class, using `handle` classes as containers as pointers, but I'm guessing that's not efficient in MATLAB.

`struct`? Extend a cell array each time its length is exceeded? More important than not copying the list is to not copy its *contents*, namely arrays.

**Edit**: I implemented Pythonic `list` and `dict` based on `cellarray` and `containers.Map`, [here](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/PyInMat).

Comment: What do you want to put in the list? More recent versions of MATLAB double the allocated space for arrays when appending individual elements in a loop. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48351041/7328782

Comment: I’m thinking this *might* answer your question, but I’m not sure: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50257074/7328782

Comment: @CrisLuengo Lists should be able to store almost anything, but let's say numeric and string arrays. My peak concern is copy behavior: manipulating the _list_ should not copy its elements. I'm aware of your first post, and second post is my [current implem](https://pastebin.com/HtZ5ffCf), but I'm uncertain about `lst{end + 1} = x`. Is there a reference page for every case where MATLAB _doesn't_ copy?

Comment: MATLAB never copies! Well, sort of. MATLAB uses "lazy copy": `b=a` creates a copy of matrix `a`, but without copying the data. Only when you modify either `a` or `b` is the copy made. So doing `c = {a,b}` puts `a` and `b` in a cell array, but doesn't copy any data. The cell array is just pointing to the same matrices as the variables `a` and `b` (until you attempt to modify one of those arrays). `c{end+1} = x` might reallocate the array `c`, but the array `c` is just an array of pointers, so this should be cheap. It will never cause a copy of the matrices in the cell array.

Comment: In your implementation, I would have `extend(self, x)` first assign to `self.data{end+length(x)}`, so that you don't repeatedly change the size of the array. I would also use `numel` instead of `length` everywhere, because `length` is more expensive (it's defined as `max(size(.))`). And `size` should take more input arguments. You can do `function out = size(self, varargin); out = size(self.data, varargin{:}); end`. Oh, and it also takes multiple output arguments. You want to make sure it behaves like [the builtin method](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html).

Comment: @CrisLuengo This extends my understanding based on [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/avoid-unnecessary-copies-of-data.html), good to confirm. Thanks also for taking look at my code: I overloaded all "size-ness" operators just for whatever calls on them; good catch on `extend`. I'm thinking redoing all that using `dlnode` for sake of long lists.

Comment: Make sure you time your use cases with both implementations. I have the gut feeling that `dlnode` is orders of magnitude slower than a simple cell array. Even in C++ it is often better to use a plain array over a linked list, in MATLAB this difference must be much more significant. I might be wrong, don't take my word for it, time your code!

Comment: @CrisLuengo I certainly had this concern, also on how big an "empty" MATLAB class is (ones in Python come with lots of baggage, don't want `1e7` instances of those). I might still be a little paranoid on copies and `dlnode` appears safer. May be best to just roll with cellarray and revisit if it disappoints. Briefly, do your copy descriptions also hold of [dlarray](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/dlarray.html) packed in cellarray?

Comment: Yes, MATLAB does the lazy copy for everything.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I made an implementation for list and dict [here](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/PyInMat), thanks for the help so far. Any further feedback is welcome and appreciated. -- Also you may notice a strange code structure (emulating Python imports), I thought of making an [SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) post, but dunno if there's much to be said - [in one pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIWNL.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathworks themselves have [an example linked-list implementation](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/matlab/matlab_oop/example-implementing-linked-lists.html?lang=en), where each elements seemed to be an instance of a class. It's bound to be less efficient than a uniform array in many operations, but could be ideal for many others.

Alternatively, you can relay on Java LinkedLists like discussed in [here](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/answers/312595-finding-element-in-java-linkedlist). Whether performance improves depends on the actual usage scenario.

I guess the most efficient way will be using MEX function to call C routines, save for hardware specific optimizations. That's likely to be far-fetched for most applications that starts in MATLAB.

Comment: Yeah, that example is what I had in mind. If they're doing that then maybe it's practical. Java appears [limited](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14485432/10133797) in handling MATLAB types. I'll give it a go, thanks.